# getting values inputs from dynamically created editTexts

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have created a LinearLayout with 4 Inputs of string and double data type with two buttons(Add More, and Proceed).

When i click on the AddMore Button, and another set of input fields is added below the first one according to how many times it is clicked,(I'VE DONE THIS)

When i click on the Proceed button,
* I want to get values supplied on the dynamic fields according to the number of times the views are added below. and i want to make calculations together with the first 4 fields and then pass these values to the next activity for further processing

The dynamic fields

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/product_name_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:hint="Product Name"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/product_number_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"

    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Product Number"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/product_price_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"

    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Product Price"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/product_quantity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"

    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Product Quantity"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

The Proceed Button

```
public void btnProceed(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DisplayActivity.class);


    // ******** making sure the inputs gets values before proceeding to 
    the next phase
    if(productName.getText().length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You need to fill out the fields to 
        continue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if(productNumber.getText().length() ==0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "fill out the second field to continue", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if (productPrice.getText().length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out the third field", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if (productQuantity.getText().length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out the last field", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        // getting text from the user using the standard fields
        pName = productName.getText().toString();
        pNumber = Double.parseDouble(productNumber.getText().toString());
        pPrice = Double.parseDouble(productPrice.getText().toString());
        pQuantity = 
        Double.parseDouble(productQuantity.getText().toString());

        //for the dynamically added textViews
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = 
        getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        for (EditText editText : allEds) {
            editor.putString("key" + editText.getTag().toString(), 
            editText.getText().toString());
        }
        editor.commit();

        ArrayList<String> allTexts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (EditText e : allEds) {
            allTexts.add(e.getText().toString());

        }

        //sending the standard recieved texts to the next activity
        intent.putExtra("name", pName);
        intent.putExtra("number", pNumber);
        intent.putExtra("price", pPrice);
        intent.putExtra("quantity", pQuantity);

        //sending the dynamically received values
        intent.putExtra("Text", (Serializable) allTexts);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

*EDITED *

THE ADD MORE BUTTON

```
public void onAddField(View view) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
    //adding the new row before the add field button.
    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 
    1);
}
```

THE RECEIVING ACTIVITY

```
    productName = findViewById(R.id.product_name_main);
    productNumber = findViewById(R.id.product_number_main);
    productPrice = findViewById(R.id.product_price_main);
    productQuality = findViewById(R.id.product_quantity_main);

    //GETTING THE DYNAMIC DATA
    others = findViewById(R.id.other_items);
    Intent collectDynamicData = getIntent();
    ArrayList <String> allTexts = (ArrayList<String>) 
    collectDynamicData.getSerializableExtra("text");
    others.setText((CharSequence) allTexts);


    //getting the first items from the first activity
    getName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
    getNumber = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("number");
    getPrice = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("price");
    getQuantity = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("quantity");

    //formatting the numbers
    DecimalFormat formate = new DecimalFormat();
    String resultNumber, resultPrice, resultQuantity;
    resultNumber = formate.format(getNumber);
    resultPrice = formate.format(getPrice);
    resultQuantity = formate.format(getQuantity);


    //SETTING THE OUTPUT
    productName.setText(getName);
    productNumber.setText(resultNumber);
    productPrice.setText(resultPrice);
    productQuality.setText(resultQuantity);
}
```

I expected that will send all the input data to the next activity, but it only sent the data from the first four (4) input fields which is not dynamic and it didn't send the dynamic data

Comment: What does contain `allEds`?

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have several views with similar ids, so system find only the first view with specified id. 
You need to add your layout to array and and assign every dynamic layout unique id (For example: `View.generateViewId()`). After it you need to iterate over an array of layouts and execute `findViewById()` inside each layout (For example: `layouts [i] .findViewById (R.id.edit_text)`).

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast response. Please can you show some code examples of how to implement this, it will be much appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**Update** -
Instead of using your own view, try using a dynamically created `EditText` and see if that works,

```
public void onAddField(View view) {
    //Create dynamic EditText
    EditText dynEditText = new EditText(this);
    //Add dyn edittext to layout
    parentLinearLayout.addView(dynEditText, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 
    1);
    //Add the EditText to allEds
    allEds.add(dynEditText);
}
```

---

You don't seem to be adding your dynamically created `EditText` to `allEds`.

```
public void onAddField(View view) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
    //adding the new row before the add field button.
    parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 
    1);

    //Find the EditText in rowView
    EditText dynEditText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.dynEditText);
    //Add the EditText to allEds
    allEds.add(dynEditText);
}
```

You're also using the key "text" instead of "Text" in the receiving activity.

```
//ArrayList <String> allTexts = (ArrayList<String>) collectDynamicData.getSerializableExtra("text");
//Should be
ArrayList <String> allTexts = (ArrayList<String>) collectDynamicData.getSerializableExtra("Text");
```

---

Your code seems to run fine when I test it, your problem probably lies elsewhere. A few things you could check are,

1. Place a breakpoint at the `intent.putExtra("Text", (Serializable) allTexts);` line and you can use the debugger to check if the `EditText` values are gotten properly.
2. Check if you add your dynamically created `EditText` to the `allEds`.
3. Ensure that you're getting the `ArrayList` from the intent properly in the second `Activity`.

   ```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   ArrayList<String> allTexts = (ArrayList<String>) intent.getSerializableExtra("Text");
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I've tried it but its still not working. Please if you can give me some example , that will help a lot. Thanks again

Comment: I believe i'm missing something out and i can't seem to figure out what i am missing

Comment: Add the code you have for dynamically creating `EditText` and the code for getting `ArrayList<String>` in the second `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Chrisvin Jem. I have edited and added all the requested code above, please check it out. Thanks again.

Comment: I've updated my answer, check it and mark the answer as correct if it works. Cheers.

Comment: I've tried it and still not working. But how am i suppose to collect the individual data from each dynamic editTexts input given that they are added dynamically? Thanks

Comment: You should be able to get them directly using `getText`, did you try using a dynamically created `EditText` instead of using your inflated view?. And what seemed to be the result from debugging the values using breakpoints?